# iOS: strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS with 2 modal viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 modals viewControllers: 1) **Filters** 2) **Sign-in**.

In **SignInviewController** I have a `user_login` textField, which automatically becomes active (shows keyboard):

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.user_login becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

If I open **SignInviewController** first, everything is fine, keyboard shows up, I can sign-in.

But if I open modal **FilterviewController** first, change filter settings, click "Done", then open  **SignInviewController** - I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the moment when iOS tries to show keyboard.

**SignInviewController** & **FilterviewController**  are not connected between each other - totally separate - so I can't understand how **FilterviewController** causes crash of **SignInviewController**.

**UPDATE**:

Xcode highlights `[self.user_login becomeFirstResponder];` line with green color and note: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xb1057169)`

**UPDATE-2**:

Just noticed one more thing causing the same error. If I open modal Filter, click on any textField (keyboard shows), then click "Done" (Filter closes), then open Filter again and click on textField again, I get the same EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

**UPDATE-3**

user_login:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet UITextField *user_login;
```

Comment: add some code or crash log.

Comment: Xcode just highlights `[self.user_login becomeFirstResponder];` line with green color and note: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xb1057169)`

Comment: user_login seems to be nil.

Comment: why don't you move [self.user_login becomeFirstResponder]; to viewDidAppear ?

Comment: it doesn't change anything, I get same error.

Comment: could you add the code for the declaration of your self.user_login

Comment: @Basheer_CAD added; thanks for taking your time

Comment: one more question, do you register for NSNotifications keyboardWasShown, or keyboardWasHidden etc. anywhere in your viewControllers? @oyatek

Comment: @Basheer_CAD no I don't

Comment: @Basheer_CAD you were right, problem was caused by NSNotifications.

Comment: :), do you want me to add an answer ?

Comment: I already added detailed answer by myself but I did +1 for all your comments :) thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by `DAKeyboardControl` library. I used it in one of my View Controllers, and I  forgot to do this:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view removeKeyboardControl];
}
```

`DAKeyboardControl` subscribes for keyboard NSNotifications - and it needs to be removed by the method above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the text field pointed to by `user_login` has been deallocated. Is `user_login` an `unsafe_unretained` property?

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is often a result from an object being deallocated and messaged afterwards. You can find out more about the error by enabling zombies:

In Xcode's scheme editor switch to the Diagnostics tab and check "Enable Zombie Objects".